# Replace material whith sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

How to add sprite to player material with script. I have a shop menu of player and when a like to select one sprite i like to add to player material but I don't know how to do this. I have my code but just this I don't know how to add. This is my code I made like this but don't work can someone tell me how to add `playersprite` to `playermaterial`.

```
public Material playerMaterial; // --> (player Material)          
public Sprite[] playerSprite;  // --> (Sprite i wish to add to the player)   
GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index];

private void SetSprite(int index)
{
    activeSpriteIndex = index;
    GameManager.Instance.state.activeSprite = index;
    GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index];
    spriteBuySetText.text = "Current";
    GameManager.Instance.Save();
}
```

Comment: Sprites aren't Materials. You need to change the material's *texture.*

Answer (score 0):

A Unity3d material is more than just a texture so you need to set the texture of material via the SetTexture() method or mainTexture property. I'm assuming it's the Main Texture you want to change and not the bump or lighting maps.

```
public Material playerMaterial; // --> (player Material)          
public Sprite[] playerSprite;  // --> (Sprite i wish to add to the player)   

private void SetSprite(int index)
{
    activeSpriteIndex = index;
    GameManager.Instance.state.activeSprite = index;
    GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial.mainTexture = GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index].texture;
    spriteBuySetText.text = "Current";
    GameManager.Instance.Save();
}
```

Comment: You also might want to consider doing a null check on GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index]. the whole line could explode if you have an empty place in your playerSprite array.

Comment: Dont work this code its says: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Sprite' to `UnityEngine.Texture'.

Comment: I have to ask - why aren't you just using a spriterenderer? Why are you using a material?

Comment: the Sprite has a .texture property, but I'm worried we are headed down the wrong path in that this is a lot of hoops to do what a SpriteRenderer does with the .sprite property

Comment: okay tell me how to make with material. I made with material but again this code is wrong with material. GameManager.Instance.playerMaterial.material= GameManager.Instance.playerSprite[index];  i made this code

Comment: Can you help me please.